# Net Core 2.0 - JWT Bearer not protecting routes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I followed the tutorial to configure JWT with Identity on Net Core 2.0 : https://medium.com/@lugrugzo/asp-net-core-2-0-webapi-jwt-authentication-with-identity-mysql-3698eeba6ff8

Author clearly states that there is need to add [Authorize] to protect endpoints,
but I want to protect all endpoint unless explicitly specified [AllowAnonymous].
I read other tutorials about JWT Bearer and they look exactly the same but authors saying that it should request authorization by default...

This is my Startup.cs

```
 // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // ===== Add DbContext ======
            var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("dbContext");
            services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql().AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(connectionString));

        // ===== Add Identity ========
        services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        // ===== Add JWT =====
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear(); // => remove default claims
        services
            .AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

            })
            .AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                cfg.SaveToken = true;
                cfg.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidIssuer = Configuration.GetSection("jwt")["issuer"],
                    ValidAudience = Configuration.GetSection("jwt")["audience"],
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration.GetSection("jwt")["key"])),
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero // remove delay of token when expire
                };
            });

        services.AddMvc();

        // Register the Swagger generator, defining one or more Swagger documents
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
        });

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {

            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }


        // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.
        app.UseSwagger();

        // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.), specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
        });

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvc();

        dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
    }
}
```

Can't find anything in docs looking differently so I would know what I have to change... 
I can call any route without the token in headers.
Has anyone an idea?

Comment: I know. I don't say that he wrote anything wrong, sorry if my question was missleading. I just want to adjust it to secure all routes by default and use [AllowAnnonymous] to make it open instead of all routes open and using [Authorize]

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. @Mihail's answer should be enough for what you need then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use filters like this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
{...}
services.AddMvc(config =>
{
   var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
   config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Clearly explained: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/secure-data